# When using s3fs, 'ls' command shows nothing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

I've been trying to set up Amazon S3 as a backup service for my files. I'd like to use the service by mounting it as a drive on my ubuntu install, and the [s3fs project](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) is supposed to make that possible. But I'm having some trouble with it. I believe I have successfully installed fuse and s3fs. When I mount a drive, I get no errors; however, when I then enter the directory and issue the 'ls' command, nothing happens. If I create a test file with a command like:

```
touch file.test
```

the file shows up in the aws console. But I am unable to either see the files that are already present in the bucket or navigate into subdirectories using the 'cd' command. I've done a bit of sniffing around in the projects google forum, and I think I have discovered that s3fs cannot see any contents of an s3 bucket **unless** those files or directories have been created using s3fs. Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is this really the way this project has been designed? Is this a bug? Or is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

S3FS uses special 'hidden' zero byte files to represent directories, because S3 doesn't really support directories. If you try a mkdir on your mounted s3fs bucket then use the AWS file browser you should see this in action. If your S3 bucket contains a directory structure that was not created by S3FS then S3FS won't recognise that structure. S3FS only works well with buckets that are only ever manipulated using S3FS.

After trying to use s3fs for a project I was working on I concluded that it was better to be exposed directly to the limitaions of S3, rather than using something which attempts to hide those limitations.

Comment: thanks for the very clear answer! i think may end up not using s3fs as well. the alternative i've found are the [s3 tools](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd). besides being rather slow in uploading, they serve my purposes well as what i really want to do here is use s3 as a backup. however i have to say that i don't fully understand yet why amazon has designed their s3 service with so many limitations -- i'm sure it's my own ignorance.

Comment: With s3fs, in my experience, you can also "mkdir <existing pseudo-directory that's already in S3>" and the files under that pseudo-directory in the bucket become magically visible to s3fs because it now is aware that it should check for files there, so it discovers them... but it is still true that s3fs is best used where buckets are only written-to by s3fs (reading from elsewhere is fine).  In time, I suspect that you will come to see that some of the "limitations" in S3 actually some of its strengths.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible to access s3 with ls command:

```
ls: reading directory /mnt/s3/: Operation not permitted
```

Only with the s3cmd ls.

Comment: Use `sudo ls /mnt/s3/`.

Comment: Also make sure your AWS S3 credentials have policy access to perform the action you need to perform. Mine didn't list because my access credential had limited its access policy scope.